# Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels. Confusion matrix for Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

I have seen lots of answers with regards to this particular error. I haven't found any answer to it with specifics to my particular issue. Therefore, my problem

This is what I do:

```
    shortness_breath_data <- data_categ_nosev %>%
dplyr::select(shortness_breath, obesity, asthma, diabetes_type_one, diabetes_type_two, obesity, hypertension, heart_disease, lung_condition, liver_disease, kidney_disease, Covid_tested, Gender)
```

And this is `put(head(shortness_breath_data))`:

```
structure(list(shortness_breath = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), obesity = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    asthma = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes_type_one = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    diabetes_type_two = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), hypertension = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    heart_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), lung_condition = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    liver_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), kidney_disease = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Covid_tested = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("negative", 
    "positive"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Other"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), problems = structure(list(row = c(2910L, 
35958L), col = c("how_unwell", "how_unwell"), expected = c("a double", 
"a double"), actual = c("How Unwell", "How Unwell"), file = c("'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'", 
"'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))
```

And I divide this into training and testing dataset.

```
shortness_breath_data$shortness_breath <- as.factor(shortness_breath_data$shortness_breath)

n <- nrow(shortness_breath_data)
set.seed(22)
trainingdx <- sample(1:n, 0.7 * n)

train <- shortness_breath_data[trainingdx,]
validate <- shortness_breath_data[-trainingdx,]

train %>% distinct(shortness_breath)
validate %>% distinct(shortness_breath)
```

And just to do the same in case it will ease you job in finding the issue, I provided `dput(head(train))` and `dput(head(validate))`

train dataset:

```
structure(list(shortness_breath = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), obesity = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    asthma = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes_type_one = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    diabetes_type_two = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), hypertension = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    heart_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), lung_condition = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    liver_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), kidney_disease = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Covid_tested = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("negative", 
    "positive"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Other"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), problems = structure(list(row = c(2910L, 
35958L), col = c("how_unwell", "how_unwell"), expected = c("a double", 
"a double"), actual = c("How Unwell", "How Unwell"), file = c("'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'", 
"'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))
```

validate dataset:

```
structure(list(shortness_breath = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), obesity = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    asthma = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes_type_one = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    diabetes_type_two = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), hypertension = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    heart_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), lung_condition = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    liver_disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), kidney_disease = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Covid_tested = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("negative", 
    "positive"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", "Other"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), problems = structure(list(row = c(2910L, 
35958L), col = c("how_unwell", "how_unwell"), expected = c("a double", 
"a double"), actual = c("How Unwell", "How Unwell"), file = c("'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'", 
"'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))
```

And then, I build my logistic regression model with stepwise, forward method.

```
null_model <- glm(shortness_breath ~ 1, data = train, family = "binomial")

fm_shortness_breath <- glm(shortness_breath ~., data = train, family = "binomial")

stepmodel <- step(null_model, scope = list(lower = null_model, upper = fm_shortness_breath), direction = "forward")
```

Then I get my summary model and store the predictions in the source data frame.

```
summary(stepmodel)

validate$pred <- predict(stepmodel, validate, type = "response")

validate$real <- validate$shortness_breath

train$pred <- predict(stepmodel, train, type = "response")
train$real <- train$shortness_breath
```

Then I plot my ROC curve with no problem:

```
plot.roc(validate$real, validate$pred, col = "red", main = "ROC Validation Set", percent = TRUE, print.auc = TRUE)
```

Yet, when I am trying to get my confusion matrix, this is where I get my error. But this is my code:

```
cm_stepmodel <- confusionMatrix(stepmodel, validate)
```

And then, the error comes in:

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

With Show Traceback:

```
3.
stop("`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.", call. = FALSE)
2.
confusionMatrix.default(stepmodel, validate)
1.
confusionMatrix(stepmodel, validate)
```

I simply do not see the problem. And tried several other options but did not work. I have reproduced, step by step the exact approach I am undertaking. And I do not get my answer. Also, I have tag this issue with RMarkdown as well, alongside caret and R, just in case.

Also, libraries used are:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(conflicted)
library(tidymodels)
library(ggrepel)
library(corrplot)
library(dplyr)
library(corrr) 
library(themis)
library(rsample)
library(caret)
library(forcats)
library(rcompanion)
library(MASS)
library(pROC)
library(ROCR)
library(data.table)
```

Comment: Why are you putting the stepwise model `stepmodel` and your whole validation set `validate` in `confusionMatrix`? Shouldn't you put just the two vectors of predictions and true labels? For instance `confusionMatrix(validate$pred, validate$real)`

Comment: I think you should give vector to `confusionMatrix()`, not dataset or model. Did you try `confusionMatrix(validate$real, validate$pred)`

Comment: Can you list all the packages you are using at the top via library statements?

Comment: @bzki done it. thank you.

Comment: @RicS the same error I get.

Comment: @demarsylvain I get the same error

Comment: So @demarsylvain and @RicS are both on to the right answer. However,  your predicted values are probabilities (since you said `type = "response"`). You need a predicted label instead, to compare with the true label. I'm not especially familiar with caret, but that's what I think is going on. You could simply use 0.5 as the threshold for predicting the label, I suppose.

Comment: okay, so instead of  type = "response" , I shall do write this type = "prob" ?

Comment: There's no option from predict.glm that will give you the label automatically -- you have to convert your probabilities to labels, I think.

Comment: @bzki I simply do not get it. Sorry. I probably need a code to understand this.

Comment: I will try to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your predicted probabilities to labels, and then run your confusionMatrix on this:

```
validate$pred <- predict(stepmodel, validate, type = "response")
validate$pred_label <- as.factor(ifelse(validate$pred >= 0.5, "Yes", "No"))
confusionMatrix(validate$real, validate$pred) # Error
confusionMatrix(validate$real, validate$pred_label) # This will work
```

Check that you are correctly assigning labels as in your original dataset in the `validate$pred_label` statement.

I'm not particularly familiar with `confusionMatrix`, but the general idea is that you make predictions of labels and compare to the actual labels of your data. It threw an error because you were comparing labels with probabilities -- you needed to assign the labels. Please correct me if I made a conceptual error or coding mistake above.

Comment: thank you. That is straightforward answer. And funny enough, to my previous years models, I have done exactly the same. Yet, the mistake here in this case is obvious. Thank you!